# UINavigation Bar is offset with tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Good afternoon! I am writing a small app for iPhone. I have a problem - I slip down the table cells, and with it moves navigationbar. I rummaged all related issues but could not find the problem. I am hope for your help.

My Code in ViewDidLoad():

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
self.cellName = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sport", @"Media", @"Love", nil];
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(85, 0, 0, 0);
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SlideMenu.png"]] ];
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

I offset my self.tableView on 85px down and navigation bar offset with tableView (( 
Thanx for help

Comment: Are you wanting to scroll through your tableview and leave the navigation bar hovering in the same spot?  And is your result that the navigation bar scrolls away when you start scrolling?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog My table is static - a sidebar. I just have a back background - picture in which the application logo at the top, and I decided to move the table cells down - to show the logo. But along with the cells shifted navigation bar. I'm trying to make it invisible but it does not help. [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

Comment: Are you using a UITableViewController or a UIViewController?  If it is a UITableViewController, I would suggest making it a UIViewController and adding  an IBOutlet connection to the tableview.  Then you could move the tableview wherever you need without affecting the NavigationBar.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog So I did. I was initially so

Comment: I don't understand your comment, did you get it working?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog https://www.dropbox.com/s/k76p3xq6nyuqhlj/stackoverflow.png?dl=0